# error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'mask' in package 'com.globalsolutions.mygov'

Tags: android, jar

I am using [markedEditText](https://github.com/toshikurauchi/MaskedEditText) library in Android application.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/sticky_view_step_1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <!-- ФИО -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fioLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="@string/step1_fio"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#777777" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fioLabelStar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fioLabel"
                android:text=" *"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#fe6969" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fioText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/step1_fio_hint"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:enabled="false"
            style="@style/EditText">
        </EditText>

        <!-- Email -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/emailLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="@string/step1_email"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#777777" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/emailLabelStar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/emailLabel"
                android:text=" *"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#fe6969" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/emailText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/step1_email_hint"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:enabled="false"
            style="@style/EditText"/>

        <!-- Номер телефона -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/phoneLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="@string/step1_phone"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#777777" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/phoneLabelStar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/phoneLabel"
                android:text=" *"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#fe6969" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/phoneText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/step1_phone_hint"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:enabled="false"
            style="@style/EditText"/>

        <!-- Пол -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/genderLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="@string/step1_sex"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#777777" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/genderLabelStar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/genderLabel"
                android:text=" *"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#fe6969" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/genderContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >
            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/genderRadioGroup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1.0" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/genderManRadioButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/btn_radio"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:text="@string/step1_male"
                    android:textColor="#777777" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/genderWomanRadioButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/btn_radio"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:text="@string/step1_female"
                    android:textColor="#777777" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Дата рождения -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/birthDateLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="@string/step1_birth"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#777777" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/birthDateLabelStar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/birthDateLabel"
                android:text=" *"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#fe6969" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <br.com.sapereaude.maskedEditText.MaskedEditText 
            android:id="@+id/birthDateText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            mask:mask="####-##-##"
            android:enabled="false"
            style="@style/EditDate" />

        <!-- Серия/номер паспорта -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/passportLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="@string/step1_passport"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#777777" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/passportLabelStar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/passportLabel"
                android:text=" *"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#fe6969" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/passportText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/step1_passport_hint"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:enabled="false"
            style="@style/EditText"/>

        <!-- Кем выдан -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/issuedByLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="@string/step1_issued_by"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#777777" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/issuedByLabelStar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/issuedByLabel"
                android:text=" *"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#fe6969" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/issuedByText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/step1_issued_by_hint"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:enabled="false"
            style="@style/EditText"/>

        <!-- Место жительства -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/locationLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="@string/step1_location"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#777777" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/locationLabelStar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/locationLabel"
                android:text=" *"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#fe6969" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/locationText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/EditText"
            android:hint="@string/step1_location_hint"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"/>

        <!-- Дата выдачи паспорта -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/issuedDateLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="@string/step1_issued_date"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#777777" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/issuedDateLabelStar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/issuedDateLabel"
                android:text=" *"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#fe6969" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <br.com.sapereaude.maskedEditText.MaskedEditText 
            android:id="@+id/issuedDateText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            mask:mask="####-##-##"
            android:enabled="false"
            style="@style/EditDate" />

        <!-- Действителен до -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/activeTillLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="@string/step1_active_till"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#777777" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/activeTillLabelStar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/activeTillLabel"
                android:text=" *"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#fe6969" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <br.com.sapereaude.maskedEditText.MaskedEditText 
            android:id="@+id/activeTillText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            mask:mask="####-##-##"
            android:enabled="false"
            style="@style/EditDate" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This xml is giving this error:

> error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'mask' in package
>   'com.globalsolutions.mygov'
>
> error: Error: Color value not valid --
>   must be #rgb, #argb, #rrggbb, or #aarrggbb (at 'mask' with value
>   '####-##-##').

This piece of xml should refer to markededittext.jar library. But it is somehow referring to my applicaiton package 'com.globalsolutions.mygov'. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you provide your full XML layout?

Comment: @michael_, I have added full xml